# How to stop Windows 10 crashing on Dell Optiplex XE2

Tags: windows-10

I have a Dell Optiplex XE2 (i5 processor) running windows 10. Three times recently it has crashed after a windows update, which I have fixed by resetting Windows.

No specific part of any windows update seems to be causing the error, as it crashes in a slightly different way each time (last time just becoming totally unresponsive.) Yes, I can delay updates, but that only works for up to 30 days or so.

My guess is that the root cause may be a hardware error in the processor or the hard drive. Is there a reliable diagnostic tool which can check both of these for faults? Or have I missed some other possible cause?

Comment: Refer to this https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/how-to-fix-windows-10-crashing-issues-easily/

Comment: When you say "crashed", what exactly did it do? If you got a blue screen, we'd need to know what that screen said to really help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution although still don't know the cause, thanks @HarshShah for your link :

- ran sfc /scannow - no issues found
- ran chkdsk /r - no issues found
- Reboot F5 to run onboard system diagnostics. Full test revealed no issues
- Clean install of windows 1809 (just because I had that iso handy) on a new SSD and install
- ran system update to bring up to current windows version - no issues

I had previously done the clean install on the old drive but it crashed on update. So new SSD has fixed it although no issues were found with the old drive.